# Listing unique values grouped by categories using QGIS

Tags: qgis, unique-value

At 3.24.3, I need to create a list of the unique values in field A, grouped by field B.

In my example, a data table contains a series of inspection dates (field A) that occurred across several districts (field B). I need a single output table that contains the unique inspection dates for each district.

My (unwieldly) workaround is to select those records in the first district, then apply the *List Unique Values* tool on that selected set.  I then repeat for each subsequent district.  Unfortunately, this creates a separate output table for each district.

How can I create a single output table that contains the unique dates found in each district?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of my original data, with the duplicate records highlighted:

[image]

And here is the desired list of unique *inspection_date* values, grouped by the field *district*

[image]